# Retornar o valor na lambda e não a query montada pela lambda

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Fiz essa lambda

```
OfferUri = OfferUri.Select(s => s.Items.Where(a => a.SubscriptionId == s.Id).Select(n => n.Id).FirstOrDefault()).ToString()
```

e quando vou ver o que ela me retorna, eu tenho isso na propriedade

```
SELECT     
        CASE WHEN ([Project5].[C1] IS NULL) 
        THEN 0 ELSE [Project5].[C2] 
        END AS [C1]    
    FROM ( SELECT         
            [Project3].[C1] AS [C1],         
            (SELECT TOP (1)             
                [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id]            
            FROM [dbo].[SubscriptionItem] AS [Extent3]            
            WHERE ([Project3].[Id] = [Extent3].[SubscriptionId]) 
            AND ([Extent3].[SubscriptionId] = [Project3].[Id])) AS [C2]        
            FROM ( SELECT             
                   [Project2].[Id] AS [Id],             
                   [Project2].[C1] AS [C1]            
                   FROM ( SELECT                 
                             [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],                 
                             (SELECT TOP (1)                     
                                  [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id]                    
                                  FROM [dbo].[SubscriptionItem] AS [Extent2]                    
                               WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[SubscriptionId]) 
                               AND ([Extent2].[SubscriptionId] = [Extent1].[Id])) AS [C1]                
                               FROM [dbo].[Subscription] AS [Extent1]                
                               WHERE [Extent1].[OrderId] = 4661 )  AS [Project2] )  AS [Project3])  AS [Project5]
```

executando no banco recebo isso

```
C1
---
3845
3848
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é como retornar esses últimos valores na propriedade e não a query

**EDIT1**

A questão toda é que quando eu executo essa query

```
var csp = OfferUri.Select(s => s.Items.AsEnumerable().Where(a => a.SubscriptionId == s.Id).Select(n => n.CspSubscriptions.Where(sel => sel.OriginSubscriptionItemId == n.Id).Select(r => r.OfferUri))).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

eu pego isso

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]]
```

e deveria pegar isso

```
031C9E47-4802-4248-838E-778FB1D2CC05
A6C5A400-70B4-458F-AAF9-DADE77A70418
```

Esse é o problema que eu estou passando, não consigo trazer o valor da execução da query.

Comment: Esse GUID que você quer está dentro do campo `id` da tabela?

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que quando você chamou o `.ToString()` a query ainda não havia sido executada, se você colocar um `.ToList()` (ou `.FirstOrDefault()` se não espera uma lista como retorno) antes dele você resolverá:

```
OfferUri = 
    OfferUri
        .Select(s => s.Items
            .Where(a => a.SubscriptionId == s.Id)
                .Select(n => n.Id).FirstOrDefault()).ToList().ToString()
```

Na verdade não faz muito sentido usar o `ToString` numa lista (imagino que seja uma lista que você espera, pois no resultado que colocou de exemplo retorna mais de um valor), provavelmente está usando o `ToString` por engano.

Comment: So uma correção  seria  melhor Utilizar FirstOrDefault() ao  Invéz de First() pois se a query retonar nenhum valor ela vai  gerar uma exception

Comment: @MarcosBrinner, dei o exemplo do First por que não sei se o retorno sempre terá resultado, mas é uma boa observação. Troquei na resposta pra evitar o problema.